# Remove duplicates from an array and add the elements of the other array

Tags: arrays

I want to get this output form the below code, but always there is something wrong:

XX0 0.503
XX1 0.4
XX2 0.2
XX3 0.303
XX4 0.4
XX5 0.002

```
    String[] sarray  = new String[]{"XX0", "XX0", "XX0", "XX0", "XX1", "XX2", "XX3", "XX3", "XX3", "XX4", "XX5"};
    double [] amount  = new double[]{0.2, 0.001, 0.002, 0.4, 0.2, 0.001, 0.3, 0.002, 0.4, 0.002, 0.002};

    String s;
    double x=amount[0];
    try{
    for(int i=0;i< sarray.length;i++){
        s = sarray[i];
        while(sarray[i+1].equals(s)){
            amount[i]=amount[i]+amount[i+1];
            sarray[i+1]= "";
            amount[i+1]=0;
            s = sarray[i+1];
        }
    }

    }catch(Exception ex){}

     for(int i=0;i< sarray.length;i++){
         System.out.println(sarray[i]+"  "+amount[i]);
     }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: What is the 'something wrong' or what is the current output?

Comment: What output are __you__ getting ?

Comment: After awhile looking at your codes.... I'm not sure if you understand what you are trying to write. You declare an double x to be 0.2, and then you're not using it.  And you're checking If the next array like sarray[0] and sarray[1] is equal only, you're not checking against the whole array. Not only that, I don't know what you're checking what against what too.

Comment: Also, the __while__ loop does not increment i, hence does not terminate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to add the corresponding values of `sarray` and `amount` array. So, `XX0` should equal to `0.2 + 0.001 + 0.002 + 0.4` = `0.603` and not `0.503`.
Assuming that is the case, you could try this code:

> String[] sarray  = new String[]{"XX0", "XX0", "XX0", "XX0", "XX1", "XX2", "XX3", "XX3",      "XX3", "XX4", "XX5"};
>               double [] amount  = new double[]{0.2, 0.001, 0.002, 0.4, 0.2, 0.001, 0.3, 0.002, 0.4, 0.002, 0.002};

```
double x=amount[0];
int i;
try{
for(i=1;i<sarray.length;i++){
    if(sarray[i-1].equals(sarray[i])){
        x += amount[i];
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(sarray[i-1]+"  "+x);
        x = amount[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(sarray[i-1]+"  "+x);
}catch(Exception ex){}
```

Note: This does not edit the arrays as you have done, but gives the desired output.